# Shopify product.title only shows the variant

Tags: collections, shopify, title

Hey I have the following problem:

In Shopify, I have sent my colours per product on the Collection Page as a separate product (at least that's what it looks like).
This all fits, however, instead of the product name under the image on the collection page, the first variant is now displayed, e.g. Black XS instead of the hoodie name.

I used the following code in my snippet.

```
  <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="product-item-meta__title">{{ product.title }}</a>
```

I need to somehow be able to render the product name here.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please clarify what "I have sent my colours per product on the Collection Page as a separate product" means? Thanks

Comment: Yes sorry if it's not clear.

Comment: Each Color is on the collection Page rendert as an Product. So If I have an T-Shirt in 4 diffrent colors you will see at the Collection page 4Products. I only render the variant image.